# Two norms on the space of Lipschitz functions

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

We define on the vector space of Lipschitz functions on $\mathbb{R}$ two norms that are:
$$N_1(f)=|f(0)|+\sup_{x\neq y}{|f(x)-f(y)|\over |x-y|}$$ $$N_2(f)=|f(0)|+\sup_{x\neq 0}{|f(x)-f(0)|\over |x|}$$

Are these two norms equivalent?

Comment: Sorry, for the formatting, the domain is $R$

Comment: This is kind of absurd question ... In essence, you ask if derivative at $0$ bounds derivative at any other point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norms are inequivalent. The slope at $0$ does not dominate slopes at other points. Let $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 0& x\le 0\\ x^n & 0\le x\le 1\\
1 & x>1
\end{cases}$$ Then
$$0\le {f_n(x)-f_n(0)\over x}\le 1$$ On the other hand
$${f_n(1)-f_n(1-n^{-1})\over n^{-1}}\\ =n [1-(1-n^{-1})^n]\approx n(1-e^{-1})$$
Hence $$N_1(f_n)\le 1,\quad N_2(f_n)\  \gtrapprox  n (1-e^{-1})$$